# Stackoverflow em Árvores AVL

Tags: java, recursão

O programa que eu estou a realizar, pretende simular um sistema que contabiliza a passagem de carros por pórticos, para tal o programa recebe vários tipos de comandos e não termina enquanto não receber uma linha vazia.

São três tipos de comandos, os quais são: o `PASS 00AA00 I`, indica que o veículo de matrícula 00AA00 passou por um pórtico e que a situação de pagamento de passagem pelo pórtico encontra-se irregular.

Se for `PASS 00AA00 R`, neste caso o carro passou pelo pórtico também, mas a sua situação de pagamento de pasagem encontra-se regular.

o `UNFLAG 00AA00`, apenas altera a situação de pagamento de passagem para regular, ou seja, se o veículo com aquela matrícula se encontra com a situação irregular, passa-a para regular, se estiver a regular, mantém-se; por último temos o STATUS 00AA00, este comando realiza um output, verificando o número de passagens de uma veículo com a matrícula 00AA00 e a sua situação de pagamento de passagem, se este não existir, realiza um output NO RECORD.

Para resolver este problema, foi-me pedido para recorrer ás árvores AVL e o meu código é o seguinte:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TP2_probB {

    static No raiz = null;
    static double numRotacoes = 0;
    static double numAtravessos = 0;
    public static class No {

        private String matricula;
        private int porticos;
        private boolean estadoRegular;
        private No pai;
        private No filhoEsq;
        private No filhoDir;
        private int balanceamento;

        public No(String matricula, int porticos, boolean estadoRegular) {
            this.matricula = matricula;
            this.porticos = porticos;
            this.estadoRegular = estadoRegular;
            this.pai = null;
            this.filhoDir = null;
            this.filhoEsq = null;
            this.balanceamento = 0;
        }

        public void setEstadoRegular(boolean estadoRegular) {
            this.estadoRegular = estadoRegular;
        }

        public void setPai(No pai) {
            this.pai = pai;
        }

        public void setFilhoEsq(No filhoEsq) {
            this.filhoEsq = filhoEsq;
        }

        public void setFilhoDir(No filhoDir) {
            this.filhoDir = filhoDir;
        }

        public void atribuiNoEsq(No noEsq) {
            this.filhoEsq = noEsq;
        }

        public void atribuiNoDir(No noDir) {
            this.filhoDir = noDir;
        }

        public void atribuiPai(No noPai) {
            this.pai = noPai;
        }

        public void aumentaPortico() {
            porticos++;
        }

        public String getMatricula() {
            return matricula;
        }

        public boolean isEstadoRegular() {
            return estadoRegular;
        }

        public No getPai() {
            return pai;
        }

        public No getFilhoEsq() {
            return filhoEsq;
        }

        public No getFilhoDir() {
            return filhoDir;
        }

        public int getBalanceamento() {
            return balanceamento;
        }

        public void setBalanceamento(int balanceamento) {
            this.balanceamento = balanceamento;
        }


        @Override
        public String toString() {
            String estado;
            if (estadoRegular == true) {
                estado = "R";
            } else {
                estado = "I";
            }
            return matricula + " " + porticos + " " + estado;
        }
    }

    private static  No duplaRotacaoFilhoEsq(No k3)
    {
        k3.setFilhoEsq(rotacaoFilhoDir(k3));
        return rotacaoFilhoEsq(k3);
    }

    private static No duplaRotacaoFilhoDir(No k3)
    {
        k3.setFilhoDir(rotacaoFilhoEsq(k3));
        return rotacaoFilhoDir(k3);
    }

    private static No rotacaoFilhoDir(No k1) {
            No k2 = k1.getFilhoDir();
            k2.setPai(k1.getPai());
            k1.setFilhoDir(k2.getFilhoEsq());
            if(k1.getFilhoDir()!=null)
            {
                k1.getFilhoDir().setPai(k1);
            }
            k2.setFilhoEsq(k1);
            k1.setPai(k2);
            if(k2.getPai()!=null) 
            {
                if(k2.getPai().getFilhoDir()==k1)
                {
                    k2.getPai().setFilhoDir(k2);
                }
                else if(k2.getPai().getFilhoEsq()==k1)
                {
                    k2.getPai().setFilhoEsq(k2);
                }
            }
            balanco(k2);
            balanco(k1);
            return k2;
        }

    private static No rotacaoFilhoEsq(No k1) {
            No k2 = k1.getFilhoEsq();
            k2.setPai(k1.getPai());
            k1.setFilhoEsq(k2.getFilhoDir());
            if(k1.getFilhoEsq()!=null)
            {
                k1.getFilhoEsq().setPai(k1);
            }
            k2.setFilhoDir(k1);
            k1.setPai(k2);
            if(k2.getPai()!=null)
            {
                if(k2.getPai().getFilhoDir()==k1)
                {
                    k2.getPai().setFilhoDir(k2);
                }
                else if(k2.getPai().getFilhoEsq()==k1)
                {
                    k2.getPai().setFilhoEsq(k2);
                }
            }
            balanco(k2);
            balanco(k1);
            return k2;
        }

    private static int altura(No aux)
    {
        if(aux == null)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(aux.getFilhoEsq() == null && aux.getFilhoDir() == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (aux.getFilhoEsq() == null)
        {
            return 1 + altura(aux.getFilhoDir());
        }
        else if (aux.getFilhoDir() == null)
        {
            return 1 + altura(aux.getFilhoEsq());
        }
        else
            return 1 + Math.max(altura(aux.getFilhoEsq()), altura(aux.getFilhoDir()));
    }

    private static void balanco(No tmp)
    {
        tmp.setBalanceamento(altura(tmp.getFilhoDir())-altura(tmp.getFilhoEsq()));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String linha;
        String[] aux;
        ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (true) {
            linha = input.nextLine();
            if (linha.isEmpty())
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                aux = linha.split(" ");
                if (aux[0].compareTo("PASS") == 0) {
                    No novo;
                    if (aux[2].compareTo("R") == 0) {
                        novo = new No(aux[1], 1, true);
                    } else {
                        novo = new No(aux[1], 1, false);
                    }
                    if (raiz == null) {
                        raiz = novo;
                        balanco(raiz);
                    } else {
                        procuraNo(novo);
                    }
                } else if (aux[0].compareTo("UNFLAG") == 0) {
                    if (raiz != null) {
                        No no = new No(aux[1], 0, false);
                        mudaEstado(no);
                    }
                } else if (aux[0].compareTo("STATUS") == 0) {
                    if (raiz == null) {
                        output.add(aux[1] + " NO RECORD");
                    } else {
                        No no = new No(aux[1], 0, false);
                        output.add(procuraRegisto(no));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < output.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(output.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("Número de Rotações: "+numRotacoes+"\nNúmero de atravessias: "+numAtravessos);
    }

    public static void procuraNo(No novo) {
        No aux = raiz;
        while (true) {
            if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) == 0) {
                aux.aumentaPortico();
                aux.setEstadoRegular(novo.isEstadoRegular());
                equilibra(aux);
                break;
            } else if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) < 0) {
                if (aux.getFilhoDir() == null) {
                    novo.setPai(aux);
                    aux.setFilhoDir(novo);
                    aux=aux.getFilhoDir();
                    equilibra(aux);
                    break;
                } else {
                    aux = aux.getFilhoDir();
                    numAtravessos++;
                }
            } else if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) > 0) {
                if (aux.getFilhoEsq() == null) {
                    novo.setPai(aux);
                    aux.setFilhoEsq(novo);
                    aux=aux.getFilhoEsq();
                    equilibra(aux);
                    break;
                } else {
                    aux = aux.getFilhoEsq();
                    numAtravessos++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void equilibra(No tmp) {
        balanco(tmp);
        int balanco = tmp.getBalanceamento();
        if(balanco==-2)
        {
            if(altura(tmp.getFilhoEsq().getFilhoEsq())>=altura(tmp.getFilhoEsq().getFilhoDir()))
            {
                tmp = rotacaoFilhoEsq(tmp);
                numRotacoes++;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = duplaRotacaoFilhoDir(tmp);
                numRotacoes++;
            }
        }
        else if(balanco==2)
        {
            if(altura(tmp.getFilhoDir().getFilhoDir())>=altura(tmp.getFilhoDir().getFilhoEsq()))
            {
                tmp = rotacaoFilhoDir(tmp);
                numRotacoes++;
            }
            else
            {
                tmp = duplaRotacaoFilhoEsq(tmp);
                numRotacoes++;
            }
        }
        if(tmp.getPai()!=null)
        {
            equilibra(tmp.getPai());
        }
        else
        {
            raiz = tmp;
        }
 }

    public static void mudaEstado(No novo) {
        No aux = raiz;
        while (true) {
            if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) == 0) {
                aux.setEstadoRegular(true);
                break;
            } else if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) < 0) {
                if (aux.getFilhoDir() == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    aux = aux.getFilhoDir();
                    numAtravessos++;
                }
            } else if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) > 0) {
                if (aux.getFilhoEsq() == null) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    aux = aux.getFilhoEsq();
                    numAtravessos++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static String procuraRegisto(No novo) {
        No aux = raiz;
        while (true) {
            if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) == 0) {
                return aux.toString();
            } else if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) < 0) {
                if (aux.getFilhoDir() == null) {
                    return (novo.getMatricula() + " NO RECORD");
                } else {
                    aux = aux.getFilhoDir();
                    numAtravessos++;
                }
            } else if (aux.getMatricula().compareTo(novo.getMatricula()) > 0) {
                if (aux.getFilhoEsq() == null) {
                    return (novo.getMatricula() + " NO RECORD");
                } else {
                    aux = aux.getFilhoEsq();
                    numAtravessos++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O erro que me está a surgir é StackOverflowError:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:179)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
    at TP2_probB.altura(TP2_probB.java:186)
```

Tenho alguns ficheiros de teste disponíveis neste link https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3OUu_zQ9xlGfjZHRlp6QkRkREc3dU82QmpSSWNMRlBuTUJmWTN5Ny1LaDhDN3M2WkVjYVk&usp=sharing

Espero que me possam ajudar porque eu já tentei resolver o problema e sem qualquer sucesso, daí estar aqui a pedir ajuda a comunidade. Obrigado.

Comment: Olá Miguel, tudo bem? Talvez seja melhor quebrar o problema em pedaços menores. O seu *stacktrace* indica que a pilha está estourando no método de altura. Isso pode acontecer por vários motivos... Nós em looping (ou seja, sua "árvore" AVL acabou se tornando um grafo), problemas com as condições de parada, ou até mesmo árvores muito grandes (podemos aumentar o tamanho da *stack* com a switch `-Xss`, mas esse dificilmente é problema). Sugiro que você tente isolar apenas o método de altura, depurar e entender melhor a fonte do problema.

Comment: O @AnthonyAccioly já lhe forneceu uma dica preciosa. Mas eu gostaria também de sugerir que você não calcule a altura dinamicamente. Você pode criar uma propriedade para isso no nó, e somar 1 à altura do nó pai quando adicionar um nó filho. Claro, precisará também lembrar de ajustá-las quando a árvore for balanceada.

Comment: Obrigado @AnthonyAccioly pela tua resposta tentei aumentar o tamanho da stack, mas tal como fala, não resolveria o meu problema e nem resolveu. Vou então focar-me no métedo de altura.

Comment: @LuizVieira obrigado pela tua sugestão, vou fazer exactamente isso, nunca me lembrei de ter usado essa solução!